# Knockout two-way bindings not working on checkbox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a form which generates a list options for the user, each option has a check-box,  a label and an input field.  The input field should only be shown whilst the check-box is ticked.  The options are generated through a JSON call.

However, knockout doesn't seem to be doing what I would have expected when using the visible binding.  When I check a row, the text box is correctly shown but when I uncheck it, the text box stays shown.

I suspect this is something to-do with the observable "selected" being overridden or something like that but I am stuck for ideas.

Here is a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qccQs/2/

Here is the HTML I am using in the fiddle:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'reason-template', foreach: reasonList }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="reason-template">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: selected" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" data-bind="value: date, visible: selected" />
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the javascript that I am using in the fiddle:

```
function ReasonItem(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.date = ko.observable(null);
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
};

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.reasonList = ko.observableArray([  ])
};

var vm = new MyViewModel();

new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            data: [
                { name: "Reason 1", selected: false, date: null },
                { name: "Reason 2", selected: false, date: null },
                { name: "Reason 3", selected: false, date: null }
            ]
        }),
        delay: 0
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        $.each(response.data, function(index, reason) {
            vm.reasonList.push(new ReasonItem(reason.name));
        });
    }
}).send();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to behave like I expected it to?

Comment: For checkboxs you need to use attribute `checked` not `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inputs of `checkbox` type you need to use **`checked`** instead of `value`:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
```

See [Knockout Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

Comment: That was the problem! :D  A fresh pair of eyes spotted that very quickly. Thanks.